# Get .stl format 3D mesh from Binary Mask (Segmentation)

Tags: c++, mesh, itk

I am currently able to get mesh files of [these formats](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/WikiExamples_2Meshes_2ReadWrite_8cxx-example.html#_a3) however I would like to save the mesh file as .stl. I found documentation about [this STL MeshIO Class](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1STLMeshIO.html), however, I can't seem to find the header to "include". 
Additionally, if I follow from [this](https://blog.kitware.com/writing-stl-files-from-itk-for-3d-printing/), it still asks me to enter proper file extension, as in it doesn't work when I give .stl extension.

Any help or work around?

P.S. ITK-4.11.0, VS 13 Update 5, CMake - 3.8.0.
Let me know if you need the code, I don't see a requirement here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOSTL is a remote module. When configuring ITK with CMake, you need to enable `Module_IOSTL` in group `Module`. Rebuild ITK, rebuild your program, and now you should be able to read and write `.stl` just the same as `.vtk`, `.off` etc. Hopefully, without any code changes.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know! Cheers!

Comment: _CMake Error at CMake/ITKModuleRemote.cmake:140 (message):
  error: could not find git for clone of IOSTL_

Comment: Fixed it, didn't specify Git executable in CMake

Answer (score 3):

Just adding the procedure here for someone who might be interested.

1. Get [git executable](https://git-scm.com/downloads).
2. In CMake go to advanced and add the path to the git executable[image]
3. In Modules, add Module_IOSTL [image]
4. Configure and Generate.
5. Build the ITK.sln file. (If using VS)
6. Configure and Generate your project.
7. Add `#include "itkSTLMeshIOFactory.h"`
8. Add `itk::STLMeshIOFactory::RegisterOneFactory();` before you initialize the MeshType.
9. Give file extension for `MeshFileWriter` as `.stl`, and voila!

Comment: If git.exe is in your path you don't need to manually specify it.

Comment: That's true!. I added it because I didn't have it by default. :) Thanks for the upvote!